# C# or Python Pipe Blocked

Tags: c#, python, console-application, pipe, stdin

I'm trying to simply be able to pipe the standard output of my program (written in C#) to another program (e.g. python script). My code simply writes to standard output using Console.Write(), and that works just fine when I'm not piping. The listen command just uses Console.Write() to write data from a separate Thread when it comes in from a socket that is setup.

*[Works - writes data to console as it is received]*

```
myProgram.exe listen
```

*[Does Not Work - nothing is written to console]*

```
myProgram.exe listen | python filter.py
```

I'm not entirely sure what is going wrong, and haven't thought of a way to even troubleshoot this problem. My guess is that the problem has to do with the receiving Thread somehow blocking the standard output from piping data to another process, but I don't know how to test this. I'm looking for anyone who has an idea(s) on what the problem might actually be, or a way to further troubleshoot this. If you need code to help, I'd be willing to post snippets.

How do I tell if the problem lies in C# or in Python?

**EDIT:** Note that the redirection operator (**>**) does work though. So, *myProgram.exe listen > log.txt* does in fact write the data being written to standard out to the *log.txt* file. I've also tried following the example at http://linux.byexamples.com/archives/343/python-handle-string-from-pipelines-and-list-of-param/.

***[filter.py]***

```
import sys
for line in sys.stdin:
    sys.stdout.write(line)
```

**EDIT:** Console feedback

I figured this is worth mentioning. The python script is getting called, but after waiting for 30 seconds (it should start outputting to standard out right away) I press *Ctrl + C* to stop the process and get the following.

```
>> myProgram.exe listen | python filter.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "filter.py", line 2, in 
    for line in sys.stdin:
KeyboardInterrupt
^C
```

**EDIT: @Aaronaught**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace echo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (args.Length > 0)
            {
                foreach (string arg in args)
                {
                    Console.Out.WriteLine(arg);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Receive));
                thread.Start();
                thread.Join();
            }
        }

        static void Receive()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                Console.Out.WriteLine(i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should try to narrow down the problem; for starters, write a simple C# program that does nothing but write to the standard output stream.  If that works, then set breakpoints in your existing program to see if it's ever actually reaching the console methods.

Comment: I made a very simple program to test two things. 1. That echoing passed arguments will work. 2. That the separate thread writing to standard out wasn't an issue. I then piped it to filter.py, and both worked. I'll post the simple program I used as an edit. The issue with setting breakpoints is that I cannot figure out a way to debug the program with piping in VS 2008.

Comment: You should do a thread.Join() after you start the worker thread so it can complete its work before the program exits.

Comment: Done and added above. It did not fix the issue though.

Comment: I implemented your sample application, with the addition of the thread.Join() along with your python application.  Changing the output line to sys.stdout.write("filter: " + line)  and it worked as expected. I installed the latest python 27 AMD64 on Windows 7 64.  You may want to check your python install.

Comment: if you want to attach a debugger to your test application put a Console.ReadKey() at the top, run the application from the command line including the pipe.   Attach vs.net Debug--> attach to process. then press a key in the console you ran the application from.  Though when doing this even with Flushes I didn't see any output from the python script until the C# application finished.

Comment: Ahh, I didn't know about that trick about attaching debug to a running process. That'll help with troubleshooting. I think the root of the problem has something to do with why the python script doesn't get run until the C# program is finished. Could this be a shell issue (i.e. Bash, Command Prompt, etc)?

Comment: It looks like there is some buffering going on even with Console.Out.Flush() after every write.  By increasing the volume of the output to 1000 one and changing Console.Out.WriteLine(i); to Console.Out.WriteLine("**********************************************************************" + i); the python script started getting the lines before the c# program was complete.

Comment: That is interesting. I increased the for loop amount and it takes about 8000 characters (not precise) before the buffer fills up. I've tried searching for a way to change the buffer size for Console.Out, but haven't had any luck.

Answer (score 0):

Does your program write newlines or call flush on its standard output? Maybe it's buffered and that's why you can't see anything.

Comment: I've tried both. Console.Out.Write() with Console.Out.Flush() and Console.Out.WriteLine() with Console.Out.Flush().

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput.aspx) and search for "deadlock".

Maybe it will help.

Answer (score 0):

Your python program requires 2 EOF characters to terminate. Try this.

```
import sys

line=sys.stdin.readline()
while len(line):
    sys.stdout.write(line)
    line=sys.stdin.readline()
```